# Regex match word if not as part of a specific phrase

Tags: regex

Here's an example of the kinds of imports I might have:

```
Flour, cream, salt
Butter, sour cream, vinegar
Wheat, sour cream & chive seasoning, spices
```

I'd like a regex which picks up on "cream" but only if not in the phrase "sour cream & chive seasoning"

I tried to achieve this through regex lookaheads / lookbehinds but I seem to sorely misunderstand how they work

If anyone has any advice, or advice of a different way to do this without Regex, I would be very much appreciative

Edit:

I'd also not want a match for:

```
Flour, sour cream, spice seasoning
```

As I only want to match the words within the commas

Comment: So neither `Butter, sour cream, vinegar` should match, because `cream` is not between commas, right?

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? What did you get? What did you expect?
What doesn't work with your code and where is it?

From the [regex tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info): "Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool."

Answer (score 1):

Try pattern : `(?<!sour )[Cc]ream`

Explanation:

`(?<!sour )` - negative lookbehind: assert what preceds is not `sour`

`[Cc]` match `c` or `C`

`ream` - match `ream` iterally

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/w3itXr/1)

Answer (score 0):

I'm reading this as only wanting to match `"cream"` if it's an item by itself and not part of another item. Therefore I'd probably split the input into items first, then look at the items.

1. Get a sequence of items
2. Trim off the whitespace
3. Case-insensitive compare with `"cream"`

Most languages should be able to help with that. In C# it looks something like

```
var containsCream =
  input.Split(new [] {'\n', ','})
       .Any(item =>
           string.Equals(item.Trim(), "cream", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
```

This is a bit more general than you actually asked for though, and if you're really only needing to exclude `"sour cream"` then a negative lookbehind regex is probably more efficient.